# Tabularx: How to remove extra space in the end of lines

Tags: tabularx

How can I remove the extra space at the end of each line? I want the table to end immediately after the last column and center it afterwards.

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering

\footnotesize
\linespread{1}\selectfont
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{x x x x x x x}
                \toprule
                \textbf{Number of Validators} & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{Number of Shards} & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
                \midrule
                \textbf{Size of shards} & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
                \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

\caption{Setup with the size of each shard fixed.} \label{table:shards}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is happening because you have the table set to \linewidth. This means that the table will take up all the space no matter how much text is in it. I think you would get away with {0.5\linewidth} (half the page width).

Comment: Please, provide a MWE. `x` columns aren't supported it `tabularx` by default.

Comment: @Plergux no!...

Comment: Never ignore errors, you must have multiple errors as there is no `x` column defined  so as ususal after an error the PDF is not intended to be usable, just a possible debugging aid. `tabularx` requires `X` columns.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real reason to use `tabularx` for your table. Why not just use a plain `tabular` ith columns `ccccccc`?

```
   \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Number of Validators} & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Number of Shards} & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
            \midrule
            \textbf{Size of shards} & x & x & x & x & x & x \\
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! Thanks!